# UIWebView load HTML page which consists jpeg image representation

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xcode6

I've setup simple test project with UIWebView and button action:

```
   [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.netvlies.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/wolk_600px_jpg_quality_50_progressive_11kb.jpg"]]];
```

Why each load request there is new `ImageIO_jpeg_data` and allocated memory size for that much bigger then actual image size?

I know there are lot of controversial posts about `UIWebView` leaks, how to clean it, so on.

[image]

Comment: Why do you use UIWebView to display an image? 
However, maybe you have to test it n your device, sometimes the simulator allocs other data.

Comment: I'm testing on real device iOS8 4s, actually for my purposes I'm loading web page, not just image only (this is test proj, test case)

Comment: I am having the same issue on iOS 8.0 and iOS 8.1 on both an iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. I havent checked iOS7. I've validated that I am deallocating the UIWebView correctly and I've tried all sorts of things like clearing the contents of the UIWebView before deallocation and configuring a shared NSURLCache to 0 bytes for both memory and disk. Any help would be greatly appreciated.